Configure JUnit to run on 5 threads, each using a different datasource
TL;DR How to configure my JUnit test suite to run on 5 threads, each using a different datasource?
I'm trying to speed up my SpringBoot/JUnit 5 integration tests, which currently take over 40 minutes. We're thinking of parallelizing them to save time. The issue is that some tests affect the database, which could mess up other tests if run concurrently.
Our plan is to use 5 MySQL containers and run the tests on 5 threads, each connected to a different container. This way, tests won't interfere with each other.
Can you help me configure my JUnit test suite to run on 5 threads, each using a different datasource?
